# How to show a windows form in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am wondering how to show a windows form in a WPF application. Can I just use form1.show()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. the only problem is when u try and put controls from one framework in windows of the other.. (not that problematic either btw)